# key binding to invoke more than two commands

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings, org-babel

I'm in org-mode and would like to have `C-c C-c '` run `org-edit-special` then `mark-whole-buffer` then `indent-region` then `org-edit-special` to get back out again. I've tried

```
(defun my-run-org-babel-codeblock-format ()
  "Run org babel codeblock formatting in sequence."
  (interactive)
  (org-edit-special)
  (mark-whole-buffer)
  (indent-region))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-'") 'my-run-org-babel-codeblock-format)
```

but this doesn't work:

```
my-run-org-babel-codeblock-format: Wrong number of arguments: (2 . 3), 0
```

Apparently *multiple* means no more than two commands. That is, when I remove `(indent-region)` it seems to work. Is there something I can do to have all four commands under one key binding?

Comment: `indent-region` requires at least two parameters, as in `(indent-region START END &optional COLUMN)`

Comment: I do `C-M-\\` and it automatically aligns the selected region of code. What sort of parameters do I need to tell it?

Comment: Try `(let ((x (mark)) (y (point))) (indent-region (min x y) (max x y)))`

Comment: START should be (buffer-end -1) and END should be (buffer-end 1).

Comment: BTW, mark-whole-buffer is for interactive use only: you should avoid using it in programs (precisely because it sets the mark).

Comment: And you need `org-edit-src-exit` to get out.

Comment: Why do you want to indent the code inside the block? Does it not get correctly indented according to the source code type? I experienced something similar, I even had written a function similar to yours, but then I discovered two settings that fixed the problem for me:

`(setq org-edit-src-content-indentation 0)
(setq org-src-tab-acts-natively t)`

The first removes any additional indentation of source code blocks (by default org-mode adds 2 spaces) and the second makes TAB to act as indent inside source blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Various options:

1. Make it a keyboard macro rather than an Elisp function. I.e. rather than record the functions you invoke, only record the keys you press.
2. reproduce faithfully the interactive calls to the functions:

   ```
   (defun my-run-org-babel-codeblock-format ()
     "Run org babel codeblock formatting in sequence."
     (interactive)
     (call-interactively 'org-edit-special)
     (call-interactively 'mark-whole-buffer)
     (call-interactively 'indent-region))
   ```
3. Mimic by hand the computation of the arguments:

   ```
   (defun my-run-org-babel-codeblock-format ()
     "Run org babel codeblock formatting in sequence."
     (interactive)
     (org-edit-special)
     (mark-whole-buffer)
     (indent-region (region-beginning) (region-end)))
   ```
4. Avoid commands which aren't meant to be used within functions:

   ```
   (defun my-run-org-babel-codeblock-format ()
     "Run org babel codeblock formatting in sequence."
     (interactive)
     (org-edit-special)
     (indent-region (point-min) (point-max)))
   ```
5. ...